# How to cover up a gap in a badly installed cabinet?

Tags: pipe, cabinets, sealing, temperature

The apartment I moved into has a kitchen with cabinets as most kitchens do.
I noticed that in the mornings it has been especially cold in the kitchen, and I traced the cold air to a large gap in the corner of one of the cabinets.

The photo below was taken inside the corner cabinet. You can see a pipe exposed. A lot of cold air is seeping in through here.

[image: cabinet-exposed-pipe]

**What simple things can *I* do (without involving the slow-moving elderly landlord) to patch this up and minimize the amount of cold air that gets in?**

Comment: Install literally anything that's airtight. I doubt that'll solve your actual problem, though, which is apparently poor insulation and weather-proofing in the building itself, plus a negative air pressure condition. That air will find another way in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using some ridgid foam insulation board, you could build a chase inside the cabinet.  If you take your time and cut it carefully using a straightedge, it should fit neatly in place by tension without having to use any caulk or adhesive that the property owner may frown on later.  I would build it in an "L" shape and it shouldn't take up much of your usable storage space.  Hope that helps, good luck[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rs4o.jpg)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'll do. Btw, did you use some tool to create this quick mockup or is it just a generic image from online?

Comment: I used google sketchup, It is quick and easy.

Comment: You said it should be able to stay in place using "tension". What do you mean by that exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they had to cut it out to go around the pipe.
To seal this up I would get a can of spray foam and fill the gap, the foam will seal the gap and act as insulation.